# Find source code compatible with CentOS 7.3.1611

Tags: centos, compiling, version

I recently installed CentOS 7.3.1611, which doesn't come with many packages, even when you add useful repos like EPEL, NUX, CERT Forensic Tools, etc.

In particular, gnumeric is not included, and the latest version of gnumeric (1.12.32) won't compile unless you upgrade the dependencies outside of yum, which I wanted to avoid.

Through trial and error, I found gnumeric 1.10.17 will compile, and I'm pretty it's the highest version that will.

Is there a site that lists which versions of which software will compile with CentOS 7.3.1611 or, more generally, with a given OS version?

I tried to be clever by Google searching: `"gnumeric" "1.10.17" "7.3.1611" "centos"` (and several variants), and virtually all of the results were directly or indirectly from distrowatch.com

I visited https://distrowatch.com/?newsid=09666 (for CentOS 7-1611, which I'm pretty sure is the same thing as 7.3.1611), but gnumeric isn't listed there. Apparently, however, there are similar distros that bundle gnumeric 1.10.17, strengthening my belief that there's a "major change" after that version.

Since I'll have to go through the pain myself, I wouldn't creating a page on the CentOS wiki or whatever, but was wondering if someone had already done this.

Comment: Gnumeric itself should document its dependencies. Your question doesn't reveal which parts don't work and whether that's because something is too young or too old. If you can isolate the crucial libraries (or compilers, or X architecture, or whatever the problem is) I'd suggest you google that instead. As an example, without having looked at Gnumeric's dependencies at all, I'd suggest googling the GCC, glibc, Gnome library etc versions instead of the Gnumeric and Centos versions.

Comment: And no, I don't think it would make sense for anyone to try to collect this sort of information centrally. Centrally managed distros like Debian effectively collect this information in their repo metainformation, though that too only documents what somebody tried out and considered fit for release, not necessarily what precise versions of all the declared dependencies would theoretically work together.